# node.js: Not able to auto increment the field in an array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have been working on a project and creating an rest api with the use of nodejs and mongodb. I am trying to auto increment a field that increases by 1 when a new entry is there in the database. I am using mongoose auto increment library for that. I am able to increment a field when it is in the schema. However it fails when it increment a field that is present in the array and the array is included in the schema. 
Here is my code:

```
const healthinfo = mongoose.Schema({

    cur_madications:[{

        sno:{type:String},
        medicinename:{ type: String, require: true },
        dosage:{ type: String, require: true },

    }],
    healthinfoid:{type:String},  
    medicalhistory: { type: String, require: true },
    product: { type: String },
    clientid:{type:String}
});



var HealthInfo = module.exports = mongoose.model('HealthInfo', healthinfo);
autoIncrement.initialize(mongoose.connection)
healthinfo.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, {
    model: 'healthinfo',
    field: 'sno',
    startAt: 1,
    incrementBy: 1
  });

module.exports.addhinfo = function (data, callback) {

    data.save(callback);

}

module.exports.getAllhinfo = function (callback) {

    HealthInfo.find(callback);
}

module.exports.update = function (updateobj, callback) {
    HealthInfo.update({ _id: updateobj._id},{ $set: updateobj }, callback);
}

module.exports.deletehinfo = function (delobj, callback) {
    HealthInfo.deleteOne({ _id: delobj }, callback);
}
// module.exports.getById = function (ids, callback){
//     HealthInfo.find({'clientid': { $in: ids}}, callback);
// }

module.exports.getById = function (clientid, callback){
    HealthInfo.find({'clientid' : clientid}, callback);

}
```

I am trying to increment the field sno that is present in cur_medication array. But due to some reason I am not getting the desired result. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated to your actual question, but you have a typo `cur_madications` – that should probably be `medications`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of `sno` from string to number

`sno:{type:Number}`

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: i've done everything but nothing works thanks for assistance